# Problems after installing rails on Mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails

As soon as I installed rails if I start a new app I get this error:

```
nicolamac:app2 n$ rails new app
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:88:in `materialize': Could not find multi_json-1.2.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:82:in `map!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:82:in `materialize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/definition.rb:90:in `specs'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/definition.rb:135:in `specs_for'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/definition.rb:124:in `requested_specs'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/environment.rb:23:in `requested_specs'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:11:in `setup'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler.rb:110:in `setup'
    from /Users/n/Downloads/berk-platform-0e35856/test/dummy/config/boot.rb:7
    from /Users/n/Downloads/berk-platform-0e35856/test/dummy/script/rails:5:in `require'
    from /Users/n/Downloads/berk-platform-0e35856/test/dummy/script/rails:5
    from script/rails:6:in `load'
    from script/rails:6
```

any idea?

Comment: What version of Rails are you using? You might need to update your Ruby installation since Rails 3+ requires at least Ruby 1.8.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like its trying to init a git repo in system folders. Check out [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/) and you'll have a less stressful setup.

Comment: Yeah I just saw you were using the system ruby and thought I'd point you toward rbenv since its much more sane than dealing with how Mac OS X has it configured.